Dual WANs on pfsense - default gateway and policy routing
I am configuring a pfSense system with two WANs and have the following requirements:
WAN1: This is the primary default gateway and should handle all general internet traffic.
WAN2: This is used for specific purposes, like IPsec VPN traffic, and I want to ensure traffic for these purposes routes through WAN2.
I am encountering challenges with routing behavior and default gateway configurations.
I know I can use policy routing ie. set firewall rules click advance and set default gateway. However, I have bunch of interfaces and rules, and this won't be very convenient.
So my primary question is- if I create static routes 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 with gateway set to WAN1 and then policy route ipsec to WAN2 - is this the way to go?
